# How to send Calendar invite links in email(Gmail)?

Tags: email, calendar, google-calendar

I would like to send Calendar events through mails to a group of people. I can currently share links from my Calendar but that just opens up a browser windows saying 'Untitled Event'.

For example,

If my event is Quiz No. 2 on 12th Nov at 4. Then the link should re-direct to(preferably in the Calendar app rather than a browser window) a event title 'Quiz No. 2' and the time must be set to 4. The person receiving the mail just has to click add event.

Can this be done?

**EDIT:**

I am able to send the link but it opens up in the browser. Is there any way make it open up in the Calendar app?

Comment: What Android version are you using?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Nougat 7.0

Answer (score 0):

- On your computer, open Google Calendar.
- Open an event to edit.
- Click Edit event.
- On the right, find the "Guests" section.
- Start typing the name of the person and choose someone from your contacts or type an email address to invite people who aren't in your contacts list.
- To mark a guest as optional: Next to the guest's name, click the person's icon People. If you don't see the icon, hover over the guest's name.
- When you're done editing your event, click Save.

You can invite people who don't use Google Calendar to your event. Just follow the steps above and invite the person using their email address.

Your guests will receive an email invitation. They can let you know if they are going by clicking the Yes, No, or Maybe links in the email.

Comment: The problem with this is I want to send this to a large number of people who are grouped using Outlook. Plus, I don't want to send a separate Calendar invite mail. I want a clickable link which opens up in Google Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

People who do not have access turned on with different email platforms can not get access to your calendar link.